# Is JAXB worth it for a handful of small POJOs?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb

I'm implementing a small RESTful web service, and figured I'd return XML blobs to represent the resources, which map fairly directly to some Java classes I have.

I could do custom XML encoders for each class, but I stumbled across JAXB (which I have never used), and it seemed like a clean way of avoiding having to write tedious encoding logic that I'd have to keep in synch if I add new properties to any of the classes.

**So, my question is:** is JAXB too heavyweight for something as simple as this?  Is it worth using as just something to map a basic structure, collection of beans, etc. to an XML document?

edit: I'm using Jersey to build the service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead, and a member of the JAXB ([JSR-222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) expert group.

If you are using a JAX-RS implementation ([Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/), [RESTeasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy), [Wink](http://incubator.apache.org/wink/), etc) to create your RESTful service then JAXB is the default binding layer and integrates seamlessly:

For an example see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted

Comment: Thanks.  I can't believe how easy that was.  Here I was thinking I had to build & serialize the XML myself.

Answer (score 5):

JAXB also "comes free" with Java 6. If you have control over the XML format (vs having to adopt an external schema), then JAXB is trivial to use with little more than a couple of annotations and some very simple marshalling code.

Simple toXML method:

```
    JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(YourClass.class);

    Marshaller m = ctx.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    m.marshal(waypointServer, sw);
    sw.close();
    return sw.toString();
```

XML Reader:

```
    URL url = new URL(filePath);

    JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(YourClass.class);
    Unmarshaller um = ctx.createUnmarshaller();

    YourClass yc = (YourClass)um.unmarshal(url.openStream());
```

Simple bean:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class YourClass {
    List<Stuff> stuffList;
    String id;
    int cnt;

    // getters, setters
}
```

It can get more complicated, obviously, but out of the box it can be really simple.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an opinion on whether or not JAXB is "too" heavyweight, but if you conclude that it is and you are looking for an alternative XML serializer I highly recommend [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).

It makes serializing/deserializing a real piece of cake, the default behavior makes sense in most occasions, and it's very simple to customize the output of the serialization if you need to.

Comment: Have you tried JAXB (http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html)?